# How can I redirect the default home page to another page in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, authentication, controller

I need to redirect the default CakePHP home page / or (/pages/home) to /users/dashboard page
I tried

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

and

```
Router::connect('/pages/home', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

But both are not working

Comment: What controller/action is running instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply replacing this part of `app/config/routes.php`:

```
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/views/pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

.. with something like this:

```
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Users' and
 * its action called 'dashboard' (ie. /users/dashboard)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

I sense a slight misunderstanding of the topic when you try to map from '`/pages/home`' to your dashboard. '`/pages/home`' only seems like the home page because there exists a route for that. If you want to change the homepage, you need to change the existing `Router::connect('/', ...)` rule. If you create a new rule for '`/`', underneath, it won't be executed as CakePHP will match the first route it finds.

Answer (score 1):

your first attempt

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```

Is the correct way to do it. If you are still having problems then there must be another issue.

What error do you see?